# Extjs default class properties

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, frontend, extjs4

I came across a defualt class called 'x-btn-over' on Extjs which is triggered on a mouse hover. I wanted to ask what the default properties of this class is? Also where can I find all the list of these built-in classes. The docs doesn't seem to cover these properties. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These css classes are generated when the application is built. It's not documented because it is not recommended to use them for styling ExtJS apps (though you can guess them by using an inspector tool like "Inspect Element" in Chrome dev tools).  Although nothing would stop you to use these css classes in scss files and manually created stylesheets, and personally I use it sometimes when I want to do a quick and dirty solution, it should be avoided because chances are these values could be changed or removed in a new version of the framework.

The ExtJS framework has its own [theming system](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html).
The scss variables are usually documented in the "Theme Variables" section of a component. For example: [Button theme variables](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#vars)

To find "over" related scss variables filter the properties with "over" and scroll down to the "Theme variable" section:

[image: Button "over" related theme variables]